Next.js app won't load bundled CSS from a React Component Kit
I have a repository of React components. Each component has its own .css file that gets imported into the component. These components are then bundled using a rollup config and published as an NPM package. All component CSS gets bundled up as main.css
I then install this repository into a Next.js app. While the main.css file shows up in the Node Modules when I import and use the component inside the Next.js app, the component's CSS does not appear when I render it to a page. I am able to import this repository into other applications like Docusaurus and the CSS appears.
Does anyone have any idea how I can configure the Next.js app to consume this bundled CSS without having to physically add the CSS to the Next app?

Good to know: This is different from the pages directory, where you can only import global styles inside the _app.js file.
You next js follow this docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#global-styles

I understand how Next.js styles work. I'm not trying to import styles inside the Next.js app. They're already included in the repository that's been installed. I'm trying to determine why Next won't use the styles from the npm package of component's that's been installed.
